# Is it possible to use another video card into iMac 24" 2008?

Tags: imac, video, graphics

I have an iMac 2.8 from 2008, all works like a charm for now, but I'm lacking some GPU power from my ATI Radeon HD 2600 Pro.

I checked on google and think it's a PCIe x16 card yet can't find anyone saying that upgrading this component is possible.

From the detailed info's, I can see that's plugged in by and PCIe x16, is it possible to upgrade this video card?

Comment: Setting aside whether any particular user has the skills to open and work on an iMac, this is exactly how Apple repairs any iMac with a faulty GPU card - they open, replace, test and give it back to the owner. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I don't have a problem, only when trying to run some heavy apps and that machine becames a little slower. I was just wondering if a replacement could be done for other video card with more memory. Look's like it can't :)

Comment: Oh - you wanted to upgrade to a better GPU that still fit inside the iMac body?

Comment: Yes, that's the point :)

Answer (score 1):

The 2008 iMac's use [MXM Video cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module). You could replace it but it's (very) expensive for not much more performances (High end models used a 8800M GTS (branded as a 8800GS).